# Getting 'Cannot use MongoClient' exception when refreshing django API request

Tags: django, mongodb, exception, django-rest-framework, djongo

I currently have an AWS EC2 instance running that is running a web server using Apache (httpd) to deploy the server in the instance. The project uses the Django, Djongo, and Django Rest Framework python libraries. It works initially as it gives back an API response via JSON. However, when making another API call, it comes out with the following exception:

```
DatabaseError at /profile/7/
No exception message supplied

Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: https://[redacted]/profile/7/?format=json

Django Version: 3.2.16
Python Version: 3.7.10
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'api']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 808, in __iter__
    yield from iter(self._query)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 166, in __iter__
    for doc in cursor:
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1248, in next
    if len(self.__data) or self._refresh():
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1165, in _refresh
    self.__send_message(q)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/cursor.py", line 1053, in __send_message
    operation, self._unpack_response, address=self.__address
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/_csot.py", line 105, in csot_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1335, in _run_operation
    retryable=isinstance(operation, message._Query),
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/_csot.py", line 105, in csot_wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1441, in _retryable_read
    server = self._select_server(read_pref, session, address=address)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1247, in _select_server
    topology = self._get_topology()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1203, in _get_topology
    self._topology.open()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 192, in open
    self._ensure_opened()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 592, in _ensure_opened
    raise InvalidOperation("Cannot use MongoClient after close")

The above exception (Cannot use MongoClient after close) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 65, in fetchmany
    ret.append(self.result.next())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 797, in __next__
    result = next(self._result_generator)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 830, in __iter__
    raise exe from e

The above exception (

    Keyword: FAILED SQL: SELECT "api_account"."userID", "api_account"."phoneNum", "api_account"."displayName", "api_account"."seeking", "api_account"."birthday", "api_account"."motto", "api_account"."faithID", "api_account"."job", "api_account"."hobbies", "api_account"."politicsID", "api_account"."city", "api_account"."stateID", "api_account"."bio", "api_account"."facePlot" FROM "api_account" WHERE "api_account"."userID" = %(0)s LIMIT 21
Params: (7,)
Version: 1.3.6
    Sub SQL: None
    FAILED SQL: None
    Params: None
    Version: None) was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 70, in fetchmany
    raise db_exe from e

The above exception () was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 282, in get
    return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 54, in retrieve
    instance = self.get_object()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 96, in get_object
    obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, **filter_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 19, in get_object_or_404
    return _get_object_or_404(queryset, *filter_args, **filter_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 76, in get_object_or_404
    return queryset.get(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 431, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1324, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1208, in execute_sql
    return list(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1646, in cursor_iter
    for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1646, in <lambda>
    for rows in iter((lambda: cursor.fetchmany(itersize)), sentinel):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 97, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 70, in fetchmany
    raise db_exe from e

Exception Type: DatabaseError at /profile/7/
Exception Value:
```

It starts working at one point, but then gives the exception a few other times. I could gleam that the exception actually is 'Cannot use MongoClient after close.' However, I'm not sure what exactly would be causing this as I haven't modified any other code to the underlying workings of Django. What would be causing this?

Versions of the python libraries:

Django              3.2.16
djangorestframework 3.14.0
djongo              1.3.6
pymongo             4.3.2
sqlparse            0.2.4

Answer (score 1):

Finally found out what the issue was. Turns out the version of Pymongo installed with the rest of the libraries was causing the issue. Here is the combination of library versions that seem to work best with eachother:

```
Django 4.1.2
Pymongo 3.12.1
DjangoRestFramework 3.14.0
```

Hopefully this saves someone else time. In my instance, ensuring I had Python 3.8 installed helped as well.